# Get a specific CSS whenever a page break is insert

Tags: jquery, html, css, page-break, page-break-inside

here is a outline of what my page looks like

```css
.section
{
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  /*border-bottom:5px solid gray;*/
  margin:10px;
 margin-bottom:200px;
 page-break-inside: avoid; 
}
```

```html
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
```

What i am expecting achieve here is, whenever we print this page, the first box and last box on every page should have a gray border.

Please do help out if anyone has come across such scenario before.

Currently, I am searching a JavaScript trigger which would fire on page break and help me access the first element on the page. But if anyone can suggest other line of search that would be helpful too.

Update 1:
This content is generated dynamically. The sizes of the boxes could vary. So i cant be sure how many boxes will show up on each page.

Update 2: 
I have thought about headers and footers. But that wont completely help. As i have to add certain styles to the content of the first and the last DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.section
{
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  /*border-bottom:5px solid gray;*/
  margin:10px;
 margin-bottom:200px;
 page-break-inside: avoid; 
}
div.wrapper .section:first-child {border-bottom:5px solid gray;}
div.wrapper .section:last-child {border-bottom:5px solid gray;}
```

```html
 
<div class="wrapper">
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
<div class='section'></div>
</div>
```

You can do it with simple CSS. Wrap all divs in one DIV. Now using css `:first-child` and `:last-child` you can give desired properties.

Comment: hey @Smit Raval, thanks for the reply. the contents are dynamic. So i cant be sure about where the wrapper will go.

Comment: By dynamic you mean by AJAX? @pirate-eir

Comment: No, I mean the content is generated using a C# class. The boxes will have some contents within. And as per the contents the size will vary. I need to show this on the page. And whenever ctrl+p is hit, as per the print page size, apply certain style to the first and the last box on the page.

Comment: I cant share the complete document. This is the outline of the generated HTML. The contents are removed. But its only paragraphs of description. The generated HTML contains the above structure of sections + the above CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert custom page breaks when a page is printed using an empty element in your html markup. And then simply give the element before it and after it a special class to target.

```css
@media all {
  .page-break {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  .page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  .section.before {
    border: 5px solid blue;
  }
  
  .section.after {
    border: 5px solid red;
  }
}

.section {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 200px;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='section'></div>
  <div class='section before'></div>
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <div class='section after'></div>
  <div class='section'></div>
  <div class='section before'></div>
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <div class='section after'></div>
  <div class='section'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey @Ravan, thanks for the reply. the contents are dynamic. So i cant be sure about where the wrapper will go.